# Does dotliquid support sub-templates and nested templates?

Tags: c#, dotliquid

please consider this class :

```
var dep =
            new Department
            {
                Name = "Jack",
                Employees = new List<Employee>
                {
                   new Employee()
                   {
                       Name = "E1",
                       Kids = new List<Kid>()
                       {
                           new Kid
                           {
                               Name = "K1"
                           },
                           new Kid
                           {
                               Name = "K2"
                           },
                           new Kid
                           {
                               Name = "K3"
                           },
                           new Kid
                           {
                               Name = "K4"
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   new Employee()
                   {
                       Name = "E2",
                       Kids = new List<Kid>()
                       {
                           new Kid
                           {
                               Name = "K5"
                           },
                           new Kid
                           {
                               Name = "K6"
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   new Employee()
                   {
                       Name = "E3",
                       Kids = new List<Kid>()
                       {
                           new Kid
                           {
                               Name = "K7"
                           }
                       }
                   }
                }
            };
```

so I need to define sub-template something like :

```
{{ Name }}
{% for e in Employee %}
  {{ EmployeeTemplate e }} // a Template can be an object for itself as input
{% endfor %}


EmployeeTemplate :
{% for k in Kids %}
  {{ KidTemplate k }}
{% endfor %}


KidTemplate :
{% for o in OBJECT %}
  {{Name}}
{% endfor %}
```

and result :

```
Jack
E1
K1
K2
K3
K4
E2
K5
K6
E3
K7
```

I need template as standalone block of strings so I want to know dotliquid support it or not ? 
if standalone templates support so Can we define nested templates or not ?